# Boost logger initialized in 'dynamic initializer' doesn't work with widechar

Tags: c++, c++11, boost

I'm trying to write a class to wrap Boost logger in order to log widechar.

The problem is that if the Logger is defined as **const member reference** then it throws exception 'Could not convert character encoding', otherwise it works fine.

I added a break point in Logger's constructor in Visual Studio C++, in 'Call Stack' window, it shows the call is initiated by

> ConsoleApplication1.exe!`dynamic initializer for 'logger''()

So the question is what's different if it is defined as **const member reference**?

Here's a simplest example:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>

#include <boost/locale/generator.hpp>
#include <boost/log/common.hpp>
#include <boost/log/expressions.hpp>
#include <boost/log/utility/setup/file.hpp>
#include <boost/log/utility/setup/console.hpp>
#include <boost/log/utility/setup/common_attributes.hpp>
#include <boost/log/sources/logger.hpp>
#include <boost/log/trivial.hpp>

namespace logging = boost::log;
namespace sinks = boost::log::sinks;
namespace attrs = boost::log::attributes;
namespace src = boost::log::sources;
namespace expr = boost::log::expressions;
namespace keywords = boost::log::keywords;

class Logger {
public:
    static const Logger& GetInstance() {
        static Logger logger;
        return logger;
    }

    void Log(const std::wstring& message) const {
        src::wseverity_logger< logging::trivial::severity_level > slg;
        BOOST_LOG_SEV(slg, logging::trivial::error) << message;
    }

private:
    Logger() {
        auto sink = logging::add_file_log(keywords::file_name = "sample.log");

        std::locale loc = boost::locale::generator()("en_US.UTF-8");
        sink->imbue(loc);

        logging::add_common_attributes();
    }
};

// *** The problem is introduced by line below ***
// *** If this line is removed, the logging doesn't throw exception. ***
const Logger& logger = Logger::GetInstance();

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    try {
        Logger::GetInstance().Log(L"中文");
    }
    catch (const std::exception& e) {
        std::cout << e.what() << std::endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue is basically the [static initialization order fiasco](https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/ctors#static-init-order).

There are two potential first initializations of the logger:

```
const Logger& logger = Logger::GetInstance(); // <== (a)

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    try {
        Logger::GetInstance().Log(L"中文");   // <== (b)
```

`(b)` happens after main and so is guaranteed to be run after all pre-`main()` initialization happens. `(a)` has no such guarantee and is unordered with respect to other potential static initialization. What appears to happen is that something in `Logger::Logger()` depends on another object having already been initialized - but this has not happened yet.